# exec() not returning process ID

Tags: php, exec, bioinformatics, pid, dna-sequence

I'm using the PHP `exec()` function to execute the [Canu assembler](http://canu.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quick-start.html#assembling-pacbio-data) programs, and I want to get its process ID within the same script.

The problem is `exec()` not returning any PID, even the process is running successfully.

The processes are started like this:

```
$gnuplot_path = '/usr/bin/gnuplot';

$command = 'nohup canu -d . -p E.coli gnuplot='.$gnuplot_path.' genomeSize=4.8m useGrid=false maxThreads=30 -pacbio-raw /path/to/p6.25x.fastq > /path/to/process.err 2>&1 &';
```

Currently, I try to determine if the process is still running by:

```
$pid = exec($command, $output);
var_dump($pid);
```

and also this:

```
exec($command, $pid, $return_var);
print_r($pid);
echo "$return_var\n";
```

However, I got output of `string(0) ""` and `Array ( ) 0` respectively.

Please let me know how to solve this. Thanks much.

Comment: use `ps aux | grep "process name"`, then parse the output for the *pid*, `exec()` noor other php shell relative functions return a pid, only if it was successful or not and perhaps an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is tricky. What I would do:

```
$gnuplot_path = '/usr/bin/gnuplot';
$command = 'nohup canu -d . -p E.coli gnuplot='.$gnuplot_path.' genomeSize=4.8m useGrid=false maxThreads=30 -pacbio-raw /path/to/p6.25x.fastq > /path/to/process.err 2>&1';
$command .= ' & echo $!';

$pid = exec($command, $output, $a);
var_dump($output[0]);
```

Comment: can you please explain what actually have you done here that it works i am executing a script in the background and getting the same empty string `""` as the OP is getting using `exec($command,$output);` do i have to use any specific flag in the command or something else.