# How to get execution time and memory usage of a program (c,c++,java,python,php) in php script on ubuntu?

Tags: php, c++, ubuntu, g++, shell-exec

I am trying to build an online judge website using php with laravel which can judge an user's submitted code for a problem. The server environment is ubuntu.

Each problem has an input file and corresponding output file and maximum execution time limit and memory usage limit for the code.

Suppose, for a problem input file is input.in and output file is correct.out. The judge will run the user's code and generate output file and compare it with correct.out to check whether the solution is correct. It also will check whether the code ran in the given time limit and memory limit.

Users are allowed to submit their solutions using c, c++, java, python or php

**What I have done:**

For a c++ code, suppose user's code is code.cpp. I have used exec() in my php script like this:

```
exec('g++ -o code code.cpp');
```

This creates an executable file named 'code'.

Now, I have run the executable with the input.in file and generated the the output.out file by using:

```
exec('./code < input.in > output.out');
```

This gives the output file.

Now I need to know how much time the program took to execute and how much memory it used for running or declaring variable, array or other data structures inside the code.

I can find the execution time by calculating the difference between start time and end time of the execution.

**My questions are:**

- Is there any better way to find execution time?
- How to find how much the memory the program used?
- How to check for compilation error, runtime error?

Comment: Check exit codes (from `g++` and `./code`) to check for errors. It is guaranteed for `g++`, about custom program, it may have custom logic and use its own protocol to report error, but generally if the `./code` follows common practice, it must set exit code to nonzero on error.

Comment: [time](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time)?

Comment: I tried ` $result = exec('/usr/bin/time -f "%e" ./code < input.in > output.out, $res2, $res3'); ` It shows elapsed time when I run it from ubuntu terminal, but when run inside php script, I got $result = "", $res2 = [] and $res3 = 0 @user1810087

Answer (score 0):

You answers:

1. I don't think that there are better way that just direct measurement of how long `exec` runs.
2. Profiler is the only way (`valgrind`). However, profiler will influence performance (it will decrease it drammatically). While process is still running, you can check its memory usage via following command:

   `grep VmPeak /proc/$PID/status`

Precision will be very bad, and for quick process similar to `echo` you can even have no time to run this shell command.

3. Check exit codes (from `g++` and `./code`) to check for errors. It is guaranteed for `g++`, about custom program, it may have custom logic and use its own protocol to report error, but generally if the `./code` follows common practice, it must set exit code to nonzero on error.

However, generally speaking, there are not guaranteed way to understand whether the program runs correctly, because "correctly" is about semantics and not about pure coding. "Correctly" is how the software author wants it to work. If software author thinks that the software must exit with specific code, he can do it independently from any internal errors.

See this code for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    int z = 1;
    int y = 1;
    int x = 1 / (z - y);
    return 0;
}
```

It generates "division by zero" exception.

Lets compile and execute it:

```
$ g++ program_1.cpp -o program_1
$ ./program_1
Floating point exception (core dumped)
$ echo $?
136
```

The program exits with code `136`; the reason is that default division by zero signal handler implemented by C runtime exits with this code.

If we add our own signal handler, the exit code will still be `0`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

void signal_handler (int signo) 
{
    if(signo == SIGFPE) 
        exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGFPE,(*signal_handler));
    int z = 1;
    int y = 1;
    int x = 1 / (z - y);
    return 0;
}
```

So, when you run completely unknown external code, it is near impossible to understand what does it really do; it is how viruses work for example, they behave in different way than you expect.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer 2? Here $PID is the execution process id, right? How to find it? "While process is still running..." - how to ensure it?

Comment: Yes, `$PID` is process ID. See this StackOverflow question how to get it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43012298/exec-not-returning-process-id

Comment: I got th $PID. But when ran exec('grep VmPeak /proc/$PID/status'); No such file or directory. I also checked in the proc folder, the $PID value doesn't exist there. @Vitalii

Comment: The folder exists until the process runs. When process exits, the folder is removed. It is how it works. So, you can use this trick to measure application during run-time if it runs for a long time. The only alternative is profiler, but it will influence performance hard.

Comment: I submitted a code which divides a number by zero. So, in this case. /code in exec should return non zero exit code, but I am getting 0. How to fix it?

Comment: There are no "generic" answer. The `./code` has its own semantics. By standard, if it exits in wrong way, it has to set exit code to something different than `0`. It is not compulsory, however; if `./code`, for example, catches "division by zero" signal (i. e. doesn't run default signal handler that will exit with nonzero code) and ignores the exception, the exit code generally will be `0`. So, when you run external code that has its own semantics unknown to you, you can never say whether it is executed "correctly".